# Search just one into each file

Tags: bash, grep

I am trying to know which files I need to edit, they follow a pattern that it is easy to search with grep (`grep -rnw . -e "text"`), but it returns several times the same path to the file for each match.

How can I avoid it?

Example:

```
./rnaspace_cli.py:41:from rnaspace.core.id_tools import id_tools
./rnaspace_cli.py:42:from rnaspace.core.sequence import sequence
./rnaspace_cli.py:44:from rnaspace.core.trace.event import add_seq_event
./rnaspace_cli.py:45:from rnaspace.core.trace.event import disk_error_event
./rnaspace_on_web:33:from rnaspace.ui.web.controller.rnaspace_controller import rnaspace_controller
```

Desired output:

```
./rnaspace_cli.py:41:from rnaspace.core.id_tools import id_tools
./rnaspace_on_web:33:from rnaspace.ui.web.controller.rnaspace_controller import rnaspace_controller
```

Or even better just the path and files:

```
./rnaspace_cli.py
./rnaspace_on_web
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the grep man page:

```
 -l, --files-with-matches
              Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which output would normally  have
              been printed.  The scanning will stop on the first match.  (-l is specified by POSIX.)
```

so,

```
grep -l 'pattern' files*
```

will show only filenames what contains a pattern

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand well the manual, I thought that the name would be just the literal name and not with the path.

Comment: @Llopis the name willbe echoed exactly as the grep get them. So, `grep -l 'pattern' ./*` - will print `./file1` , `./file3`, etc.. The `grep -l 'pattern' /some/path/*` will print `/some/path/file1` and so on...

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
grep -rnw . -e "text" | awk -F: '{print $1}' | uniq
```

**Edit** Explanation:

- `awk -F: '{print $1}'` - Splits the output at the `:`-sign and prints only the first part
- `uniq` - show repeated lines only one time

Comment: Please explain better your answer

Comment: Hi dear, now that's OK

Answer (score 0):

Use `-l` option in grep to get the file names only in outout:

```
grep -lrnw . -e "text"
```